# Strange "terminal" appearing

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, kde

I use ubuntu 12.04 with KDE and had two times a strange terminal or something like this appearing for like 2 seconds and then closing again in the upper right corner.

I did not see what it exactly was and it was neither konsole (default terminal) nor xterm (which is white here by default). It was some black windows with white text a bit looking like an xterm with the right configuration for a white-on-black look. It scrolled fastly some text and then disappeared. I did nothing to start it, i was using firefox the first time and reading a pdf in okular the second time.

It was too fast to recognize any text, from the appearance it could have been something like a man page scrolling in there. I am not sure if it was a terminal and i could not look fast enough, if it had a window decoration or not.

Does anybody know, what this was and what i did to start it? It seems like either some bug or even malware. But i guess a malware would be clever enough to run its stuff in a shell without a terminal window.
Some way to reproduce what may cause somthing like this would be interesting as well.

Comment: Consult some logfiles in `/var/log` for jobs having been started at that time, like a `cron` job. Start with `messages` and `daemon`, maybe `syslog` too.

Comment: I already checked logfiles, processes, netstat and my crontab, but could not find anything useful. I think a X11 program will have been started by another graphic program, though.